# PHP SoapClient modifies parameter passed in request

Tags: php, soap-client

I have magic case. I use service API based on saop WSDL. A want to take an item by it token, which I got in request earlier.
That's how my code looks:

```
$endpoint = 'https://some-domain.com?wsdl';
$client = new \SoapClient($endpoint, ['trace' => 1]);

// Requesting list of items

$itemListParameters = [
    'context' => [
       // my account credentials
    ],
    'parameters' => [
        'itemCategory' => 2, // soome category
    ]
];

$client->getItems($parameters);
$listXml = $client->__getLastResponse(); // Exececutes well

// Returns a list which looks like this after parsing xml
// $list = [
//    'category' => 2,
//    'items' => [
//        [
//            'token' => 'HdvcljhuJVHhcha...' // Binary identificator
//            'name' => 'Name1'
//        ],
//        [
//            'token' => 'ADGgvkjhuJVHhcha...' // Binary identificator
//            'name' => 'Name2'
//        ],
//        [
//            'token' => 'KHjhvHKJhuJVHhcha...' // Binary identificator
//            'name' => 'Name3'
//        ],
//    ]
// ];

/*
* Now I have request an item from gotten token from list
*/

$itemParameters = [
    'context' => [
        // my account credentials 
    ],
    'parameters' => [
        'token' => 'KHjhvHKJhuJVHhcha...' // Token of requested item fom list

    ],
];

$client->getItem($itemParameters);
$requestedXml = $client->__getLastRequest();

// And here I have my magic situation. In last requested xml I see another token.
```

Here token which I sending

```
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
```

And this is the token in my last request xml

```
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
```

Is there any one who had same issue?

Comment: If you run the first string `H4sIAAA...` through `base64_encode()`, you wil get the second string.[Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/NLVhd).  It seems like it's getting encoded again (since the first string already seem to be encoded)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson How to prevent this? Have I decode before passing this?

Comment: I don't know why (or where) it gets encoded again, but try and add it unecoded: `"token" => base64_decode('KHjhvHKJhuJVHhcha...')` and see if that works.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Nope, says wrong token. In Soap Request app everything fine with original token. May be there is another way to do soap requests using php. I use laravel as framework.